# Using Class::Interface

Tags: perl, interface

I am using the [`Class::Interface`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Interface) module, and I am trying to declare an interface that later will be implemented by some classes

But I get this error

> IPerformable is not a valid interface. start; has an implementation at /ProjectDir/IPerformable.pm line 4.`

Here is the code of the interface:

```
package Controllers::IPerformable;

use Class::Interface; 
&interface;

sub start;

1;
```

Here is an example class which `implements` the interface:

```
package Controllers::PerformTask;

use strict; 
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Exporter 'import';
use Controllers::IPerformable;
use Class::Interface;
implements('Controllers::IPerformable');

sub new {
    # code of the contructor
}

sub start {
    # implementation of the interface
}
```

This is a part of the main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/ProjectDir/Controllers';
use Controllers::PerformTask;

my $search = PerformTask->new($param1, $param2);
my $taskResult = $search->start();
print "Result of performing the task: $taskResult \n";
```

Comment: Is that *all* you have written? Is this the main program or the  `IPerformable.pm` fiile?

Comment: Thanks. Please add the names of the source files

Comment: `Controllers/IPerformable.pm`, `Controllers/PerformTask.pm`, `main.pl`

Comment: I'm sorry if this disillusions you, but we don't gaze at a few lines of code, imagine its context, and come up with a probable cause somehow. That stuff is only in Hollywood. We *test* your code and debug it, and people come here because many of us are good at debugging. But it's a complete pain when the guy asking the question wants to show *"a part of the main program"*. When we have grabbed that part we run it as it is and find that it needs `use` statements to even compile, so we guess at those and continue that way until we're finally debugging a program that we've imagined

Comment: That imagined program may well be of little use to you, but it's the best we have, and it's the reason why we sometimes get things wrong. Sorry an' all that, but we need to ***see the code that you're running***. If you gave us that then you would have a solution in moments. I hope you understand?

Comment: @Borodin I made an edit. Here is the content of main.pl

Comment: @Borodin I downloaded the module from https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Interface, took an interface from the example, changed it for the needs of my program and I don't have any idea why but it's working now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117075/discussion-between-borodin-and-bob-saginowski).

Comment: Okay, thank you for more code. Your `use lib '/ProjectDir/Controllers'` is wrong. After that, `use Controllers::PerformTask` will look for `/ProjectDir/Controllers/Controllers/PerformTask.pm` which, presumably, doesn't exist. It will have given an error `Can't locate Controllers/PerformTask.pm in @INC` which you didn't tell us about.

Comment: The morals of this tale are: *"Asking for help is like throwing a stick into the wind unless you reveal the whole problem"* and *"Listen to the sounds of the world when they are blowing in your ear"*

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this on Windows? [This bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=110071) seems like it might be apposite.

It looks like Class::Interface is unmaintained. There hasn't been a new release since 2008 and there has been no response to that bug report. I would be very wary of using it.

Modern OO Perl tend to use roles instead of interfaces. You might want to look at [Moose Roles](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) instead.

Comment: I am using Windows and I start the scripts with cygwin

Comment: or [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) if Moose is overkill

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal way to accomplish what you want using [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) and [Moo::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo::Role). You can do the same thing with [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) as well.

#### IPerformable.pm

```
package IPerformable;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moo::Role;

requires 'start';

__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```

#### PerformTask.pm

```
package PerformTask;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moo;

with 'IPerformable';

has param1 => (is => 'ro', required => 1);
has param2 => (is => 'ro', required => 1);

sub start {
    print "Implements IPerformable interface\n";
}

__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```

#### runner.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '.';
use PerformTask;

my $search = PerformTask->new({param1 => 'param1', param2 => 'param2'});
my $taskResult = $search->start;
print "Result of performing the task: $taskResult \n";
```